# Replace a string in a string with a new line (\n) in Bash

Tags: bash, string

I tried this command:

```
[silas@mars 11]$ string=xyababcdabababefab
[silas@mars 11]$ echo ${string/abab/"\n"}
xy\ncdabababefab
[silas@mars 11]$
```

I also tried to replace "\n" to '\n' and to \n . I can't use AWK or sed (this is a part from a homework exercise, and the teacher don't allow to use in this specific exercise).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use **`-e`** with `echo` as follows:

```
echo -e ${string/abab/'\n'}
```

From manpage:

```
-e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes
```

```
If -e is in effect, the following sequences are recognized:

\\     backslash

\a     alert (BEL)

\b     backspace

\c     produce no further output

\e     escape

\f     form feed

\n     new line

\r     carriage return

\t     horizontal tab

\v     vertical tab
```

Answer (score 15):

Use ANSI C style escape sequence `$'\n'` to indicate newline:

```
$ string=xyababcdabababefab

$ echo "${string/abab/$'\n'}"
xy
cdabababefab
```

Or use `zsh` to use just `\n`:

```
% string=xyababcdabababefab

% echo "${string/abab/\n}"
xy
cdabababefab
```

Answer (score 7):

In addition to above use newline by itself:

```
echo "${string/abab/
}"
```

note the quoting to avoid `\n`ewline substitution by `space`
For old bash version can be suitable:

```
printf "%s\n" "${string%%abab*}" "${string#*abab}"
```